# verify, if the string starts with given substring

Tags: php

I have a string in `$str` variable.

How can I verify if it starts with some word?

---

Example:

```
$str = "http://somesite.com/somefolder/somefile.php";
```

When I wrote the following script returns yes

```
if(strpos($str, "http://") == '0') echo "yes";
```

BUT it returns **yes** even when I wrote

```
if(strpos($str, "other word here") == '0') echo "yes";
```

I think `strpos` returns zero if it can't find substring too (or a value that evaluates to zero).

So, what can I do if I want to verify if word is in the start of string? Maybe I must use `===` in this case?

Comment: +1 because I often see people having the same trouble

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should check with the [identity operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (===), see the [documentation](https://www.php.net/strpos).

Your test becomes:

```
if (strpos($str, 'http://') === 0) echo 'yes';
```

---

As @Samuel Gfeller pointed out: As of PHP8 you can use the [str_starts_with()](https://www.php.net/str_starts_with) method. You can use it like this:

```
if (str_starts_with($str, 'http://')) echo 'yes';
```

Comment: hmmm, but how? i must verify if it `===` to what?

Comment: @Syom: Your test becomes: `if(strpos($str, "http://") === 0) echo "yes"; //returns yes`

Comment: First of all, maybe you'd better use stripos() for these use cases since the url is partly case-insensitive. Furthermore, if you would want to check for https:// as well in one expression, use
    if ( preg_match("#https?://#i",$str) ) echo "yes";

Comment: **PHP 8 has now a dedicated function `str_starts_with` for this**
`if (str_starts_with($str, 'http://')) { echo 'yes'; }`
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.str-starts-with.php

Comment: That is awesome, I will add it to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 48):

You need to do:

```
if (strpos($str, "http://") === 0) echo "yes"
```

The `===` operator is a strict comparison that doesn't coerce types. If you use `==` then `false`, an empty string, `null`, `0`, an empty array and a few other things will be equivalent.

See [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Comment: Integer `0` obviously, not string `'0'`

Comment: @JoostK: actually `'0' == 0` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: C'mon, that's just what this whole post is about!

Comment: @JoostK sorry, I didn't see your point originally. Didn't notice my own typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

PHP does have 2 functions to verify if a string starts with a given substring:

- `strncmp` (case sensitive);
- `strncasecmp` (case insensitive);

So if you want to test only http (and not https), you can use:

```
 if (strncasecmp($str,'http://',7) == 0) echo "we have a winner"
```

Answer (score 2):

check with

```
if(strpos($str, "http://") === 0) echo "yes";
```

as `==` will turn positive for both false & 0 check the [documentation](http://us.php.net/strpos)

Comment: why i can't write `'0'` insted of `0`?

Comment: Because `strpos` returns an integer if the string has been found. `===` matches only if the types matches as well, so `0 === '0'` won't match, since they differ in type (string vs. integer)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is:

```
if (preg_match("|^(https?:)?\/\/|i", $str)) {
    echo "the url starts with http or https upper or lower case or just //.";
}
```

As shown here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1):

```
strncmp($str, $word, strlen($word))===0
```

Is a bit more performant than strpos

Answer (score 1):

Starting with PHP 8 (2020-11-24), you can use [str_starts_with](//php.net/function.str-starts-with):

```
if (str_starts_with($str, 'http://')) {
   echo 'yes';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### PHP 8 has now a dedicated function [`str_starts_with`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.str-starts-with.php) for this.

```php
if (str_starts_with($str, 'http://')) {
   echo 'yes';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(substr($str, 0, 7)=="http://") {
    echo("Statrs with http://");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a big red warning in [the documentation](http://php.net/strpos) about this:

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

`strpos` may return `0` or `false`. `0` is equal to `false` (`0 == false`). It is not *identical* to false however, which you can test with `0 === false`. So the correct test is `if (strpos(...) === 0)`.

Be sure to read up on the difference, it's important: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php